# powder Missing helper file helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper, powder

hello i'm trying to make powder up and it doesnt work it shows me this error 
Missing helper file helpers//users/adel/sites/adel_blog/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb

[image]
[image]

any ideas

Comment: please post the log and also the location of your helper

Comment: Post the `home` method from your `welcome_controller.rb`. There's likely to be a typo in it.